# How to organize authentication in websockets

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have project on **php** and **websocket** server, written on **C** using `libwebsockets`.

And i have to organize some **authentication** logic between *client side js* code and *server side*.

On **php** i use sessions with `PHPSESSID` cookie set on client side after successfull login.

I can access that cookie on websocket server but,

how to compare it with `session_id()` on **server's php** side?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an API endpoint for your js on the client side to call and provide the cookie ID to a PHP function. The PHP function with then do the comparison and provided a response to the API call of either validate pass or fail.

i.e

JS calls > https://example.com/api/varifyuser with JSON

```
{ 
  user_id: 321, 
  session_id: [ENTER PHPSESSID]
}
```

PHP does comparison and returns

```
{response:   
  {
    valid_session: true, 
    session_token: 123ad12dasf312af3123, 
    user_id: 321, 
    session_id: 123ABC
  }
}
```

All comparisons should be handled on the server side to maintain security. Anything done on the client side is exposed to easy interception and vulnerabilities

---

Basic example of processing the sent key from cookie on PHP server

```
    if(preg_match("/Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n/", $headers, $match))
        $key = $match[1];

    $comparedKey = $key.'2642975-A114-47DA-95CA-342345685B11';
    $comparedKey = base64_encode(sha1($comparedKey, true));

    $upgrade = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n".
               "Upgrade: websocket\r\n".
               "Connection: Upgrade\r\n".
               "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $comparedKey".
               "\r\n\r\n";

    socket_write($client->getSocket(), $upgrade);
    $client->setHandshake(true);
    return true;
```

Comment: I mean how to compare session id, that i get in websocket server via cookie and real session id, that i can get only with session_id() in php, i.e. interaction between websocket server and php

Comment: @tzi0 have added very basic example to post above